# How do I build secure CRUD endpoints inside Dittofi?

Tags: authentication

I am working on building an app for a client inside the Dittofi Design Studio. I am on the basic package, so I cannot see by computer code.

I have built a collection of CRUD endpoints & actions & generated the code. Next & I want to make sure that some of my endpoints are only accessible by someone who correctly authenticates against them. Is there a setting for this inside the studio? How would this work for mobile apps authenticating against the endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can inside the studio.

If you look at the wrench in the bottom left, you should be able to create an "Authentication Profiles". You'd have to have users model/db table with username and password fields.

You would then have to have some sort of `/sign-up`, `/login`, and `/logout` endpoints (which would call the `login web user` and `logout web user` actions) for your authentication flow.

Finally, on the endpoint you want to lock down, if you look under its settings panel below the `name`, `label` and `content type` settings, you should be able to see how you can attach an authentication profile to the endpoint, i.e lock it down by making sure that only authenticated users can access the endpoint.

For mobile apps authentication agains the endpoints, I would generate a JSON web token (JWT) on the Dittofi end and have a secret key that's shared between the mobile apps and Dittofi to validate the token. That way the mobile app can send any requests to the Dittofi endpoints with that token. On the Dittofi end, I would have some token validation logic to validate that token.
This would require writing some custom Golang code to both generate the JWT and validate it using that secret key. That secret key can be stored in a `Global variable` (which can be though of as environment variables) accessible using that wrench in the bottom left corner of the Design studio.

Let me know if you'd like me to share the Go code that can generate the token and some example code that can validate your token using a secret key.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the authentication at the backend is better auto-generated.

After creating the table, and configuring the authentication type, then auto-generate the endpoints and workflows (Frontend actions)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34884608)